# Cypress - Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks'

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, cypress, e2e-testing

#### Current behavior

I know this kind of issue was fixed in the version `5.1.0` but ...

I'm trying to seed DB in the Node JS part logic at the `before` hook
We have the `cls-hooked` and 1 more internal npm module for sharing both use `async_hooks`
When I'm trying to import and use any of that modules I receive crashes at the test script launch:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/...[our private module name].../lib/...[file name]....js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in '/Users/.../node_modules/...[private module or cls-hooked].../lib'
resolve 'async_hooks' in '/Users/.../node_modules/...[private module or cls-hooked].../lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/.../node_modules/...[private module or cls-hooked].../package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
```

#### Desired behavior

Test script launch should go smoothly with `before` hook executing

#### Test code to reproduce

require some module in `./cypress/plugins/index.ts` with next similar logic

```
var async_hooks = require("async_hooks");
var asyncLocalStorage = new async_hooks.AsyncLocalStorage();
...
asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
```

#### Cypress Version

`^8.1.0` - `8.5.0`

```
Cypress binary version: 8.5.0
Electron version: 13.2.0
Bundled Node version: 14.16.0
```

tried Node version: `14.17.6` and `16.9.1`

the same for:

```
Cypress binary version: 7.7.0
Electron version: 12.0.0-beta.14
Bundled Node version: 14.15.1
```

#### Other

additional install of `"async_hooks": "^1.0.0"` didn't help

Using TS
`"typescript": "^4.1.5"`
OS
`macOS Big Sur 11.16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in 1 common file for both processes browser and NodeJs in Cypress.
In this case, Webpack built the bundle with 'browser' context but received NodeJs context logic. That's why the error occured.
When I used `enum` in Browser part in the file which besides that also exports NodeJs logic it (Webpack) didn't make the 'treeshaking', thus the NodeJs logic was imported into the bundle for browser process logic. ‍♂️